# Pipe Observable subscription with map angular

Tags: angular, pipe, observable

Actually I want to call another function with an array value as a parameter. I am getting the array from a subject:

```
this.shopService.$getShops().pipe(map(
  shops => {
    console.log(shops[0]);
  }
)).subscribe();
```

The subscription is based on this:

```
      private newShopsSubj = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);

  setShops(shops: any) {
    this.newShopsSubj.next(shops);
  }


  $getShops(): Observable<any> {
    return this.newShopsSubj.asObservable();
  }
```

Actually the code is working...but the `console.log` call ends with `undefined`. Somehow I am finding no appropriate solution.

I want to do like :

```
   this.shopService.$getShops().subscribe(resp => {
this.shopService.getProductsByShopID(resp[0].id).subscribe(resp
=> {do something...};});
```

But it actually fails as `resp[0].id` stays `undefined`...
My attempts with the map failed.

Any help highly appreciated...

Thanks

Hucho

Comment: Try to change the second "resp" parameter name. Instead resp, try result... Just for differentiate the two parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately not...the async timing is the problem. I don't get why the inner function somehow against all odds gets fired too early before getting the subject response...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like in other answer... if `$getShops()` is called before a value is set, you will get `undefined` as that is the initial value. You can initialize it as an empty array, or use rxjs `filter` to filter out the `undefined` value. Also I would chain these requests with for example `switchMap` or `mergeMap`, as it's not recommended to nest subscriptions. So I suggest the following:

```ts
private newShopsSubj = new BehaviorSubject([]);
public newShopsSubj$ = this.newShopsSubj.asObservable();
```

and the component code:

```ts
import { mergeMap, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

// ...

this.shopService.newShopsSubj$.pipe(
  mergeMap((shops: any[]) => {
    // do a check that that there is an object
    if (shops && shops.length) {
      return this.shopService.getProductsByShopID(shops[0].id)
    }
    // no shops, so return...
    // empty array, since assuming the above function returns array of products
    return of([]);
  })
).subscribe((products: any[]) => {
  // check if products exist and do your magic!
})
```

or like mentioned, have your BehaviorSubject initial value as `undefined` and `filter` away those value(s):

```ts
this.shopService.newShopsSubj$.pipe(
  filter(shops => !!shops)
  mergeMap((shops: any[]) => {
  // .....
```

Please note that I've used `any` here. Don't use it. Type your data to models! (I prefer interfaces).

**And remember to unsubscribe in `OnDestroy`!!**

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive solution!

Comment: You are very welcome, hopefully it helped to solve your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

`BehaviourSubject` emits the current value to new subscribers.

here you are initializing it with `undefined` initial value

```
private newShopsSubj = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);
```

So when you subscribe it as below

```
  this.shopService.$getShops().subscribe(resp => {
this.shopService.getProductsByShopID(resp[0].id).subscribe(resp
=> {do something...};});
```

Initially, it will get `resp` as undefined. 
to fix this either you can use `Subject` instead of `BehaviorSubject` or initialize `BehaviourSubject` with a proper shop object.